# Using vector instead of Loop

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have a huge matrix. I am just given an example of a matrix with size `(1*1000000).`

I am using simple `Loop` ( I do not prefer using `Loop`) to find `k`. where

`k= k(ii)=(abs(a(ii+1)-2*a(ii)+a(ii-1)))/(a(ii+1)+2*a(ii)+a(ii-1))`

However, this is fine with small matrices. If I have huge data that will take a long time. Is there any way to use vector instead of `Loop` to find `k`?

```
clear;
clc;
a=rand(1,1000000);

for ii=2:size(a,2)-1
    k(ii)=(abs(a(ii+1)-2*a(ii)+a(ii-1)))/(a(ii+1)+2*a(ii)+a(ii-1));
end
```

Comment: If you preallocate `k` your loop will be a lot faster. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with using loops in MATLAB. They used to be slow, but that is no longer the case.

Comment: @Cris Luengo. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to vectorise it, you need to know which indices of `a` you would be using at each iteration. For example, The term `a(ii+1)` with `ii` iterating from `2` to `999999` means you're using the elements of `a` from indices 3 to last and similarly find that out for other terms. Then just do the [element wise division `./`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html). `0` is manually appended at the start since in your code, you didn't explicitly store anything at first index and zero is what automatically gets stored when you skip an index.

```
k = [0 abs(a(3:end)-2*a(2:end-1)+a(1:end-2)) ./ (a(3:end)+2*a(2:end-1)+a(1:end-2))];
```

---

Performance timed with [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) on my system with R2017a and `a=rand(1,1e8);`:

```
Orig_Post = 14.3219
Orig_Post_with_Preallocation = 1.7764
Vectorised = 5.3292
```

So it can be seen that loops have been significantly improved in the newer versions. It turns out that the solution with the loop with properly pre-allocated memory for `k` is much faster than the vectorised one. The reduced performance you're experiencing is caused due to no [preallocation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) (as [*Cris Luengo*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/) already [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420999/using-vector-instead-of-loop#comment87857339_50420999)). To pre-allocate, write `k = zeros(1, size(a,2)-1);`
before the loop.

Comment: I'm not as patient as you, so I tried with `1e6` for the array size (R2017a). I see 0.055 without preallocation, 0.0087 with, and 0.018 with the vectorized code. Similar results to yours. I was expecting the vectorized code to be similar in cost or slightly better than the loop, not worse. This is maybe the third example I've seen so far where a loop is faster than corresponding vectorized code. I think in this case it's because the vectorized code needs so many more copies of the data and intermediate results. It's all about memory usage and cache misses, I'm sure.

Comment: Also, separating the indexing to avoid doing that twice: `a3 = a(3:end); a2 = a(2:end-1); a1 = a(1:end-2); k = [0 abs(a3-2*a2+a1) ./ (a3+2*a2+a1)];`. This gives me 0.011, much closer to the loop time. I tried doing `a2 = 2*...`, to not multiply twice, and also `a0=a3+a1`, to not do that addition twice, but both times the timing increased. Baffling!