# How to correct "Valid indices for 'variable' are restricted in PARFOR loops" error in matlab

Tags: matlab, parfor

I am trying to set up a `parfor` nested loop in MatLab R2016a as below.

```
N = size(A,1);
M = size(v,1);
in = zeros(N*M,1);
parfor i=1:N
   for j=1:M
      k = (i-1)*M+j;
      if sqrt(sum((A(i,:)-v(j,:)).^2))<=tol
        in(k) = i;          
      end
   end
end
```

However, I am getting the following error **Valid indices for 'in' are restricted in PARFOR loops**. Is there some way I can correct this because both arrays `A` and `v` are considerably large, over 40,000 rows for `A` and 8,000 `v`? The variable `tol` is 0.0959.

Comment: Notice that you are doing a lot of norm computations of columns of a matrix  which you can do at once using `vecnorm` if your matlab is 2017b and beyond

Comment: The version of Matlab is R2016a. As stated in the first line of the question.

Comment: Here the error comes from the fact that you parallelize `in` but parallel tasks are trying to write to the same thing

Comment: @percusse Can you elaborate in an answer below?

@SardarUsama No the value of `k` will never have the same value for multiple iterations of `i` since it also depends on `j`. `k` counts from 1:M*N.

Comment: That is a typo in the original question it is `k=(i-1)*M+j`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that MATLAB doesn't recognize that the variable `k` is slicing the matrix `in` correctly. The solution should be to index `in` using `i` and `j` separately:

```
N = size(A,1);
M = size(v,1);
in = zeros(M,N);
parfor i=1:N
   for j=1:M
      if sqrt(sum((A(i,:)-v(j,:)).^2))<=tol
        in(j,i) = i;          
      end
   end
end
in = in(:); % reshape to a column vector, as the output in the question's code
```

The other alternative, but it requires more intermediate memory, is to compute this without a loop at all:

```
A = reshape(A,1,N,[]);
v = reshape(v,M,1,[]);
in = sum(bsxfun(@minus,A,v).^2,3) < tol*tol;
in = in(:);
```

(Or something similar to that, I have not run this code... Please let me know, or fix the post, if there is a typo or other mistake.)

Comment: The first method in your answer works perfectly, thank you. I might try the second one later if time allows.

Comment: The only thing I added, was `s=v;` immediately after the `parfor` as was done in the other answer. I don't know if this was necessary but MatLab gave a warning.

Answer (score 1):

```
N = size(A,1);
M = size(v,1);
in = cell(N,1);
parfor i=1:N
    s=v;
    p=zeros(1:M,1);
   for j=1:M
      k = (i-1)*M+j;
      if sqrt(sum((A(i,:)-s(j,:)).^2))<=tol
        p(k) = i;          
      end
   end
   in{i}=single(p);
end
in=cell2mat(in);
in=reshape(in,[N*M,1]);
```

sometime matlab doesnt recognize a variable in parfor loop as "sliced variable"
, a sliced variable is a variable that has a reference out of parfor loop and each of its element only accessed by a single worker (in parfor parallel workers)
so you could use a temporary variable and collect results after the parfor loop,

NOTE 1: It is better to vectorise code in the older versions because loops didn't use to be as good as they are now in R2017 referring to ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420999/using-vector-instead-of-loop)).

NOTE 2: if most elements of "in"  are zero try using "sparse matrix" which could save a lot of memory;

Comment: This might be something I have look into on the PC I am using, but I am getting an out of memory error. Otherwise, it appears to be working. Is there a way where I can save the indices `in` as multiple variables and then recombine them outside the `parfor` loop or something else to try and eleviate this memory problem?

Comment: Would it be possible to work something like [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31972-worker-object-wrapper) into the solution?

Comment: @YixiShan , i updated the answer according to your comment , it consume much less memory than previous code , (the code could be run on 8G memory without problem)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, on my machine, there is only 4GB of memory available. I think the best solution is to modify your answer so it only in quarter intervals from 1:N or something like that, and then combine the arrays together at the end. Also I know there will be many duplicate values being stored, which I had planned to remove using `unique` at the end of the `parfor`. Is it possible to implement that sooner to shorten the size of `in`? If not then maybe running the `parfor` in quarter intervals or smaller may fix it.

Comment: @YixiShan "in" has 40000*8000=32e7 elements , each single has 4 byte so "in" size is 1.1921 GB, you need an extra free memory (about size of in) for some operations , so you could do some parfor, save data to hdd , clear variables and continue parfor and so on;